# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions jsreact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

**router.js code here**

```
import  React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import CommentList from './containers/commentview';

const BaseRouter = () =>{
<div>
    <Route exact='/' component={CommentList}/>
</div>
}
export default BaseRouter;
```

**App.js code here**

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import CustomLayout from './containers/Layout';
import BaseRouter from './router';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
class App extends Component {
render(){
return (
  <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <CustomLayout>
        <BaseRouter/> 
      </CustomLayout>
    </Router>
  </div>
 )

 }
 }

 export default App;
```

**Error here**

> ./src/router.js
> Line 6:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try with this

```
 <Route exact path='/' component={CommentList}/>
```

or

```
<Route exact path="/">
        <CommentList />
      </Route>
```

And i missed the return, my bad

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything from your router component. It looks like you were set up expecting it to be an implicit return, but it's not using the right syntax. You can do it with an implicit return like this:

```js
const BaseRouter = () => ( // Notice no "{}", just use parenthesis
  <div>
    <Route exact='/' component={CommentList}/>
  </div>
);
```

Or with an explicit return:

```js
const BaseRouter = () => { // using "{}"
  return ( // Manually return the JSX
    <div>
      <Route exact='/' component={CommentList}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks i figured it out after posting it thanks for your answer it worked.